# Find duplicates elements Google Cloud DataStore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have duplicates "email" elements in my Cloud DataStore.

The schema of the entity is:
 - ID
 - Email
 - OtherFields

I would like to find all elements which have the same email address twice or more in the database. Is it possible?

Comment: I believe you will have to scan the Datastore to determine this.

Comment: My datastore is actually very large.

Comment: What implementation language / library are you using?

Comment: We are using python on appengine.

Comment: Unfortunately, Tom is right. there is no way to do such a scan natively in the App Engine. You would need to scan every entity and then figure out the dupes. A better solution would be to use the datastore admin "backup feature" to push your datastore to BigQuery, where such a query will be much easier.

Comment: I suggest a "simple"query, pulling only id and email out, pagination using cursors. This will enable you to identify the dupes. It will cost reads, but it is a straight forward way to prices the data.